# How to use QtMultimedia/QCamera?

Tags: c++, qt, qtmultimedia, qcamera

I am creating in C++ one program, where you can create Userprofiles.
The User should have the option to take one photo with for example the notebook camera. 
I already read a lot about QCamera und try to use this. I already imported QtMultimedia in my qml file.
Now I first try to search for available camera, but there are always a lot of errors.
I don't know what I maybe forget, or why I can't find anything.
I wanted to make some tests, just to get a little bit more in contact with the QCamera class.
I included: QTextStream, QtMultimedia/QCameraInfo and QtMultimedia/QCamera

Here is my test code:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    QTextStream out(stdout);

out << QCameraInfo::defaultCamera().deviceName() << endl;

    for(int i = 0; i < QCameraInfo::availableCameras().size(); i++)
    {
        out << QCameraInfo::availableCameras().at(i).deviceName() << endl;
    }

return 0;
```

}

There is always these errors:
...\QT\test\main.cpp:23: Fehler: undefined reference to`_imp___ZN11QCameraInfo13defaultCameraEv',
...\QT\test\main.cpp:23: Fehler: undefined reference to`_imp___ZNK11QCameraInfo10deviceNameEv',
some more, but almost the same error-info.
and this one:
collect2.exe:-1: Fehler: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: Is `QT += multimedia` exist in `*.pro` file?

Comment: Thank you! Now its working!